# Cannot use this in static context

Tags: android, static, spinner, this

When I declare this method it writes error: Cannot use this in static context. The error is in the part ArrayAdapter adapter = ... Do you have any idea for which can I change it? I have absolutely no idea.

```
 protected static void myMethod()
  {
    arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c =
        db.rawQuery
        (
            "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND  name! = 'android_metadata'", null
        );

    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        while (!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            arrTblNames.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>
        (

                //HERE IS THE ERROR
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrTblNames

        );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource
    (
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
    );
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener
    (
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected
            (
                AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id
            )
            {
                selectedtable = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {
                //
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you have a reason for which this *has* to be a static method you could pass a Context as a parameter

```
protected static void myMethod(Context myContext)
```

then instead of using `this` you would use `myContext`

Comment: thank you and how can I call this method, I try MainActivity.myMethod(); but it writes error that I need some arguments in this method and I don't know which, do you have any idea?

Comment: It's depends where are you calling that from, but wherever that is, you need to pass an parameter of type `Context`
Let's assume you are calling that from some other activity, in that case you could use:

`MainActivity.myMethod(this);`

Comment: You are THE BEST! It works, thank you very much I have been finding this solution whole day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Static methods belong to a class not to an object of that class, and no instance is associated with it. The `this` keyword always refers to an instance of a class (an object) hence you can only use it when one is available, e.g. in instance methods.

You cannot use `this` in a static method so you either need to change it to be a instance member (i.e. define the method w/o `static`) or don't use `this` if the method needs to be static.

Answer (score -1):

Your method shouldn't be static:

```
protected void myMethod()
```

Static methods are used when you want to call them without instantiating that specific class.
However if a class extends `Activity` and it's not yet instantiated, it will have no Context set to it.

Since you are creating a spinner adapter and other Context dependent work, you method shouldn't be static.

Comment: "Static methods are used when you want to call it from other classes." -- Wrong. Cannot you call instance methods from other classes?

Comment: I need call this method from another activities e.g. when I add/delete table I need refresh names in spinner, so I need it static, but I dont know how to replace "this"

Comment: @luketsunami your activities shouldn't interact that way. You know that only a single one can be visible at a time. Instead when you return to the 'spinner activity' you will receive a call to `onResume`. There you can update the spinner if necessary.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp yes you're right. I didn't make myself clear enough.